# No logro mostrar las imagenes guardadas en mi BD con php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, php7

**SOLUCION:**
El problema que tuve fue que guarde la ruta de las imagenes en la base de datos con "../" que lleva a un directorio anterior, y al querer mostrar la imagen la base de datos no hallaba la ruta y no la mostraba, la solucion
cambiar la ruta a: `$ruta = '/db_images/'.$nombre;` , cambiar

```
move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], '..'.$ruta); y solo imprimir $mostrar['imagen'] dentro del src de la etiqueta <img> `<img src="<?php echo $mostrar['imagen'] ?>" alt="">`
```

este es mi codigo, la etiqueta  y  que tambien se almacenan dentro de la base de datos se muestran correctamente, pero la imagen no se muestra, solo muestra el icono de una imagen, que error tengo, ayuda porfavor?.
aqui estoy adjuntando mi codigo php, el head contiene el connect.php y si recibe todos los datos que se envian al formulario:

```
<?php require_once "./includes/head.php"; ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/articulos.css">

<?php require_once "./includes/header.php" ?>

<section class="notices">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info">
            <h2>Ultimas Noticias</h2>
            <h3>Conozca las ultimas noticias de nuestro colegio</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <?php
                
                $query = "SELECT titulo, descripcion, fecha, imagen FROM articulos ORDER BY id DESC";
                $result = mysqli_query($database, $query);
                while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
                <article>
                    <img alt="imagen" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($mostrar['imagen']); ?>">
                    <h3><?php echo $mostrar['titulo'] ?></h3>
                    <a href="#" style="color: red">Mas info aquí</a>
                </article>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php require_once "./includes/footer.php" ?>
```

Adjunto esta foto por si es necesario (donde se guardan las imagenes es en db_images que se encuentra en la raiz)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de para obtener la imagen por medio de POST, la base de datos esta configurado como longblob y en utf8 general, si necesitan alguna imagen u otro archivo php que necesiten ver me avisan porfavor, no logro encontrar una solucion a esto:

```
<?php
require_once "connection.php";

if (isset($_POST['agregar']) && isset($_POST['titulo']) && isset($_POST['descripcion'])) {
    $archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
    $nombre = $archivo['name'];
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $ruta = '../db_images/'.$nombre;
    if (!is_dir('db_images')) {
        mkdir('../db_images', 0777);
    }
    move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $ruta);
    $insert = "INSERT INTO articulos VALUES(null, '$titulo', '$descripcion', CURDATE(), '$ruta');";
    $query = mysqli_query($database, $insert);
    if ($query) {
  
    } 
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    if (!$query) {
        echo "<h3>Ocurrio un error</h3>";
        mysqli_error($database);
    }}}
```

[image: Asi se ve el valor de la imagen al inspeccionarlo]

Comment: Al parecer tenes un error cuando chequeas si el directorio existe (`!is_dir('db_images')`), lo correcto sería `!is_dir('../db_images')`

Comment: mm ya lo arregle y no sigue sin solucionarse, y antes de arreglarlo funcionaba bien y ahora que lo probe funciona igual.

Answer (score 1):

No estas guardando la imagen en la DB, lo q estas guardando es **la ruta** de la imagen en tu proyecto y en el `HTML` cuando cargas la `img` estas leyendo la imagen como si estuviera realmente guardada.

Simplemente carga en el `src` la ruta `$mostrar['imagen']`.

**PD:** Sino no funciona es que debes cambiar la ruta.

Comment: no me funciono compañero, creo que estoy confundido como deberia de quedar el codigo asi?.
`<img src="<?php echo $mostrar['imagen'] ?>" alt="">`
si es asi no me funciona

Comment: si amigo seria asi , pero en el servidor  estas guardando la ruta  $ruta = '../db_images/'.$nombre; con esta linea, sustituyela por  $ruta = '/db_images/'.$nombre;

Comment: en caso de que siga sin mostrarse la imagen abre el inspector de codigo del navegador y compartenos que valor tiene el src de la img. recuerda que en el inspector puedes editar ese valor para probar en caliente la ruta que funcione y ya despues seria actualizar en tu php la linea donde defines la ruta.

Comment: Pero si sustituyo la linea por la que me dices si los 2 puntos la imagen ya no se llega a guardar, como lo habia hecho yo si se guarda la imagen.

Comment: tienes razon debajo usas esa varible para guardar tu imagen en tu proyecto. la cuestion es que tienes que guardar en la bd la ruta sin los puntos. Te propongo lo siguiente. move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], '..'.$ruta);

Comment: ya agregue el valor del src esta en la imagen de arriba

Comment: siempre me he referido cargando la imagen asi: <img src="<?php echo $mostrar['imagen'] ?>" alt="">. No necesitas cargar la imagen en base64 debido a que no guardas tu imagen en la db.

Comment: ya lo solucione gracias, tenia que agregar un punto.
$ruta = ./db_images/'.$nombre;

Comment: perfecto. te propongo compartas un pequeño resumen con tu cambios para ayudar a los que tengan un problema parecido en el futuro.